# Can't retrieve Google Analytics for Firebase through API

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I integrated my Firebase to my Google Analytics account by following this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=ios#before_you_begin). Now I can see my custom event in Google Analytics.

I managed to use the Google Analytics reporting v4 API to retrieve data for my web site because there is a View like indicated in the figure below : [image]

I would like to use the same API to retrieve data in Google Analytics for Firebase. However, when doing the integration, no view is created like shown below :
[image]
I can't manage to find a link or a documentation to do it. Can help me about that ?
PS: I saw that it is possible to export Firebase data through BigQuery, however, I would like to avoid this possible if possible.

Regards and Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yassir,

It looks like your last screenshot shows a GA4 property, since it does not have any views. You can use the [Google Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) to access GA4 properties.